# Scala - System Command - R Batch - single quote not working for escaping argument block

Tags: scala

Here is my problem: I want to execute an R script in batch mode from scala. Here is the code I try to use:

```
import scala.sys.process._
"R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args a=1' /path/test.r".!
```

The command works when I cut and paste it in a terminal. But when I try it through scala, '--args is interpreted as the script file and I receive the Fatal error :

```
Fatal error: cannot open file ''--args': No such file or directory
```

Everything works if I remove the argument block:

```
import scala.sys.process._
"R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore /path/test.r".!
```

Any guess on how to restore the expected "normal" execution?

Thanks in advance,

BHLB

Comment: What operating system are you running the command on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running R on windows, you will need to use "s instead of 's. For instance, this works on windows:

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore "--args a=1" /path/test.r
```

When invoking from Scala, you can use string literals for convenience:

```
"""R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore "--args a=1" /path/test.r""".!
```